# Injecting dependency in abstract super class fails

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the hierarchy of classes like

```
public interface IX
{
  public String getSomething();
}
public class X implements IX
{

  @Override
  public String getSomething()
  {
    return "something";
  }

}

public abstract class A implements IX
{
  private X x;

  public X getX()
  {
    return x;
  }

  public void setX(X x)
  {
    this.x = x;
  }
  @Override
  public String getSomething()
  {
    return x.getSomething(); **//NullPointerException here ****
  }
}

public class BaseB extends A
{
  private Y y;

  public Y getY()
  {
    return y;
  }

  public void setY(Y y)
  {
    this.y = y;
  }
}

public class B extends BaseB
{
  public void test()
  {
    String something = getSomething();
  }
}
```

And I have following in my XML

```
<bean id="x" class="X" />
<bean id="y" class="Y" />
<bean class="A" id="a" abstract="true" >
    <property name="x" ref="x" />
</bean>

<bean class="B" id="b" parent="a" >
    <property name="y" ref="y" />
</bean>
```

There is something wrong with the dependency injection, X is not getting injected and its throwing a NPE as I have mentioned in the code above.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried this code (with a `public class Y implements IX`, to be able to compile) via a simple unit-test  `Assert.assertEquals(b.getSomething(),"something");` and it passed successfully using `Spring 4.0.6`.

Comment: How are you using your beans? Show us a test case.

Comment: Richardo, Class Y is not implementing IX, but i guess that wont make any difference. I dont understand why it is not working for me. BTW the spring version I am using is 3.0.7

Comment: Sotirios, I am replicating this scenario for project I am working on, these are much more complex classes. you may consider that class B is the service class and method test() is called from client. Inside method test() we are calling methods on dependencies Y and X(getSomething()). Its only the dependency X which is null while the dependency Y is properly injected.